# Android : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError File

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
 public static void deleteFile(stPath){
     File yourDir = new File(stPath); **// Line 210 in MyUtil.java**
    //
    ....
    ///
}
```

and I call it in AsynTask method:

```
private class Backup extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Exception> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgressDialog(StringUtil.getString(R.string.backucking));
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(String... params) {
            deleteFile(stPath);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
          showProgressDialog(StringUtil.getString(R.string.downloading));
        }
    }
```

When I run, it throw a error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
Android cannot find java.io.File??
I don't understand. Can you explain for me?

This is my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

--------- Stack trace ---------

    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
-------------------------------

--------- Cause ---------

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypakage/d/a/b/d
    com.mypakage.util.b.e(MyUtil.java:210)
    com.mypakage.view.main.f.a(OneView.java:1046)
    com.mypakage.view.main.f.doInBackground(OneView.java:1)
    android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
-------------------------------
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means when you run or compile the program, the compiler cannot locate a class file which it needs to run/compile, but it can't locate it and so produces the error(This can happen for a variety of reasons).  The stack trace NoClassDefFoundError:something something something should tell you the missing class.  I you post that we may be able to give you a better idea of the likely cause.

Comment: add your deleteFile() method

Comment: Can you please show the actual log? I mean, with all _caused by_ etc.

Comment: maybe there is some problem inside StringUtil? show us full log

Comment: Are the exceptions that your code mentions defined on your platform?

Comment: @Hikaru try creating a new clean project and run it in a new virtual android device and see if this happens again (just in case)

Comment: @Hikaru and after you solve your problem (I suspect you already did), please answer your own question so that the next person who encounters it can find the solution via Google.

Comment: I updated my post. This error rarely occurs. I didn't find the solution via Google.

Comment: Is your permissions ok ?

Comment: Yes, permission is ok

Comment: This error is quite common when using Proguard.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not about missing `java.io.File`, but rather about a call to a missing class 
from your own package - `mypakage.d.a.b.d`.

This is of course not the name of one of your classes. Your code seems to be obfuscated, I.E. you're (or your IDE is) running Proguard on the compiled code prior to installing it on the device.

Proguard performs a lot of changes to your code. Two of the relevant changes are:

1. Changing class names (hence the .d.a.b.d).
2. Removing what Proguard feels is a dead code, I.E. code that's never been called.

A misconfigurastion of Proguard mighty cause a class you do use to be removed nonetheless.

So please:

1. Disable Proguard and try running the app without obfuscating it, so we could verify that Proguard is indeed the culprit.
2. [Use ReTrace to deobfuscate](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#) `mypakage.d.a.b.d`, so you would know the real name of the missing class.
3. Paste us what's in line 210 of MyUtil.java.
4. Paste Proguard's configuration file (proguard.conf).

Comment: Thanks to Vaiden. I will try it!

Comment: Please report the resolution and mark the solution if applicable